# Why my JS function is not defined when the file that has it is already being called at the footer of the page?

Tags: javascript, undefined, referenceerror

I have a couple of input form items that I want to be shown when the user clicks a button. [Here's the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmuzy1py/1/)

**So, I've created an html button and referenced my JS method when it's clicked:**

```
<button type="button" id="mostrarOpcionesFiltrado" onclick="return mostrarFiltros.esconderFiltros();" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Mostrar Opciones de Filtrado</button>
```

**I've created a file formularios.js and added it to the bottom of my page:**

```
<script src="js/formularios.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**And finally created my JS file (formularios.js) where I take away the classes that maintain the items hidden:**

```
var mostrarFiltros = {

    esconderFiltros: function() {
        if(document.getElementById('mostrarOpcionesFiltrado').clicked) {
            console.log('mostrando las opciones de filtrado');
            $('#apellido').removeClass('sr-only');
            $('#email').removeClass('sr-only');
            $('#dni').removeClass('sr-only');           
            $('#username').removeClass('sr-only');          
        }   
    },

} //cierre del objeto mostrarFiltros
```

And these are the parts of the form that should be affected by clicking the button:

```
<div id="apellido" class="form-group sr-only">
        <label for="exampleInputName2">Apellido</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido">
      </div>
      <div id="email" class="form-group sr-only">
        <label for="exampleInputName2">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
      </div>
      <div id="dni" class="form-group sr-only">
        <label for="exampleInputName2">DNI</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dni">
      </div>
      <div id="username" class="form-group sr-only">
        <label for="exampleInputName2">UserName</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
      </div>
```

My problem is that when I click the button, the console throws an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: mostrarFiltros is not defined

What Am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the formularios.js file is being loaded? Can you see it in the dev tools?

Comment: Any other errors in the console, e.g. syntax errors from that file?

Comment: Yes, it's added into the footer of every page.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the HTML is there. If the server cannot find the file it will not serve it.

Comment: look into source in dev tool?

Comment: In general, using `addEventListener` is less messy than mixing JavaScript into the HTML.

Comment: Double check the network tab in your browser console and make sure that the request for the JS file completed successfully. If it didn't, or is still pending, and you click that button you would get this type of error.

Comment: Okay, what about having to reference jQuery before he uses it in the function?

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: I've changed the location of the file to the head, and put a reference to it with the full url, it does appear when I look into the source code as well.

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/bmuzy1py/1/

Comment: your fiddle is executing your javascript inside an onLoad handler which means any variables declared in your JS pane won't be accessible outside of the onLoad function. Click the little gear icon and change it to wrap it in the body or head and it will start working

Comment: If the button with the id "mostrarOpcionesFiltrado" was clicked... remove CSS classes, that's was what I hoping to achieve...

Comment: I just tried it in jsbin and it works fine but if I try to do same thing I got the same error as you got. Just trying to help.

Comment: What are the important question? I'm trying to answer everything, I'm reading all comments...

Comment: I'm just learning JS, and I just wanted to remove css classes when the button is clicked

Comment: Yes I agree there is nothing wrong with the code. But there is definitely something with the environment witch is causing this.

Comment: Yes. The only difference is that I added `"use strict";` at the very top of it.

Comment: So, why it won't work on jsfiddle? I've changed the onload option to wrap it in head and then in body, and it won't work.

Comment: I'm referring to the contents of formularios.js

Comment: I would suggest to try this in different browsers and see if the result is same. There can be the browser issue.

Comment: I see! But why it won't work? I mean, should that mean that "if the button with id # is clicked..."

Comment: You seem to have lost interest in your actual question. Odd.

Comment: I've solved the actual issue with the jsfiddle example, but would like to know why the if condition wouldn't work.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. How can jsFiddle solve code in a script not being available in your test environment?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there are a few things wrong with yout jsFiddle (check the settings on your javascript section of jsFiddle):

- your Javascript is defined "onLoad" so its not visible on the global scope.
- You are using jQuery selectors, but haven't added jQuery in your frameworks and extensions.

Secondly, as another user mentioned, even if the function was defined, the actions you wish to have will not be executed because of your if statement.

Also, I would suggest you either

- Stick to pure js https://jsfiddle.net/nd0vmtvz/ :

  ```
  var mostrarFiltros = {

        esconderFiltros: function() {
          document.getElementById('apellido').classList.remove('sr-only');
          document.getElementById('email').classList.remove('sr-only');
          document.getElementById('dni').classList.remove('sr-only');
          document.getElementById('username').classList.remove('sr-only');


        },

    }
  ```

or

- Go with jQuery https://jsfiddle.net/q2xd65xc/ :

  ```
  var mostrarFiltros = {

      esconderFiltros: function() {

           $('#apellido').removeClass('sr-only');
           $('#email').removeClass('sr-only');
           $('#dni').removeClass('sr-only');
           $('#username').removeClass('sr-only');
       },

    } //cierre del objeto mostrarFiltros


  $(function() {
       $('#mostrarOpcionesFiltrado').click(function() {
           mostrarFiltros.esconderFiltros();
       });
  })
  ```

Finally, to answer your original problem, the file containing your javascript is most likely not being loaded. You can verify this with devtools/firebug. It would be helpful if you posted your folder structure as well.

Answer (score -1):

Are you still getting the ReferenceError or is it that code isn't doing what you want it to do. Once you get past the ReferenceError, the code won't work because you have this line:

```
if(document.getElementById('mostrarOpcionesFiltrado').clicked){
```

That condition will never be true so the code inside that condition won't work. See this jsFiddle for a working version: https://jsfiddle.net/bmuzy1py/4/